# How to solve the problem of displaying wrong user email addresses on Sendgrid?

Tags: authentication, email, sendgrid

I am currently working on Sendgrid, a customer communication platform that helps businesses send transactional emails. The majority of emails are delivered and received, to email addresses that appear to be correct.

But for the past few days, I've been seeing this kind of recipient: user12345@gmail.fr or user13527@outlook.com.

On the "Activity" interface, where are listed all the recipients, some addresses are displayed correctly, and others seem to be encrypted, with the beginning of the mail as "user...@" as you can see above.

I don't know if this problem comes from the API connected to an external database, or from the tool I'm using Sendgrid (display problem?) or from the recipient.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: "some addresses are displayed correctly, and others seem to be encrypted (...) as you can see above" I think you did not post the image or reference